# How to implement hyperledger fabric erc20 wallet like metamask?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode, hyperledger-fabric-ca

As I known fabric wallet register, enroll and save wallet id server side. So fabric wallet seem be centralize.
I want user control your wallet id as Metamask with private key, and account id.
Hope everyone can help me. Thank so much!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.